# Gradle file to Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I want to add this dependency to my maven spring application.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.regulaforensics.com/RegulaDocumentReaderWebClient")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.regula.documentreader:webclient:5.+")
}
```

I am having this code which is of a gradle file and I want to add this dependency to my Spring application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application pom.xml, you add a repository tag then, a dependency tag, like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>regulaforensics</id>
        <url>https://maven.regulaforensics.com/RegulaDocumentReaderWebClient</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

then

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.regula.documentreader</groupId>
        <artifactId>webclient</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did so and updated the project with Maven; however, I am still getting this error in the pom.xml **"Missing artifact com.regula.documentreader:webclient:jar.5.+" **

Comment: Sorry, of course you will have to specify version, "5.+" is not precise, if you'll check repo https://maven.regulaforensics.com/RegulaDocumentReaderWebClient/com/regula/documentreader/webclient/ the latest 5th version is 5.8.4, so change tag into: `<version>5.8.4</version>`

Comment: Thanks very much for your response!!. Yes, it worked after updating the version of the dependency.